# Setting timeout on c# httpclient not working

Tags: c#

I set timeout to 1 millisecond, but when I test, all the http calls seem to work fine, almost like it's ignoring the timeout. How do I get it to work?

Thanks

```
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)
    }; // re-use the object

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a GET call.
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri, string token_type, string access_token, string accept, string content_type)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        if (content_type != null) request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", content_type);
        if (accept != null) request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept)); // ACCEPT header
        if (token_type != null && access_token != null) request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token_type, access_token);
        HttpResponseMessage g = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (g.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ExternalException(await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), (int)g.StatusCode);
            //throw new ExternalException(await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() + "      Reason: " + g.ReasonPhrase + "      Message: " + g.RequestMessage + "      Status Code: " + g.StatusCode + "      Token Type: " + token_type + "      Content Type: " + content_type + "      Accept: " + accept, (int)g.StatusCode);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a POST call. The content type should be embedded in the postData already.
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string token_type, string access_token, HttpContent postData, string accept)
    {
        string mes = await postData.ReadAsStringAsync();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
        {
            Content = postData // CONTENT-TYPE header
        };

        if (accept != null) request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept)); // ACCEPT header
        if (token_type != null && access_token != null) request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token_type, access_token);
        HttpResponseMessage g = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (g.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ExternalException(await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), (int)g.StatusCode);
            //throw new ExternalException(await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() + "      Reason: " + g.ReasonPhrase + "      Message: " + g.RequestMessage + "      Status Code: " + g.StatusCode + "      Token Type: " + token_type + "      Post Data: " + mes + "      Accept: " + accept, (int)g.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this? It seems to throw a TaskCanceledException for me when I call `await GetAsync("https://www.google.com", null, null, null, null);`. http://share.linqpad.net/omrxnf.linq

Comment: It seems to work as intended. Are you awaiting the task, or otherwise trying to get the result of it? The exception wouldn't show itself until you do this.

Comment: Add a CancellationTokenSource to your tasks

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this ? I am facing a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that this code is executed on a background thread. If you never wait it (by explicitly waiting, or getting the "Result" somewhere, etc.), the exception itself is omitted inside the background thread (becomes an unhandled exception). You should prevent this from happening, of course, by getting the results (or wait) at some point. In your case, you can use it like:

```
GetAsync.Wait();
```

This will throw an exception for you.

Comment: [There's no background thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), and [you should observe `Task` results using `await`, not `Wait`/`Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).